# can NFC in android device detect LF RFID tags?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I want to know whether NFC can detect Low frequency RFID readers like say 30khz to 300khz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is NO. The whole RFID technology is based on the concept that both the tags and the readers should operate at the same frequency. Like you have said, NFC works at 13.56 MHz and hence a NFC enabled device would be able to read/scan only 13.56 MHz compliant RFID Tags

Comment: Unfortunately no. You need to have an antenna that operates LF and a related reader that is able to read it. So as is off the shelf, you wont be able to use the NFC chipset on the phone to work with LF tags

Comment: Do you know any antenna for Android?